# Responsive File Manager not displaying Images on TinyMCE

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, responsive-filemanager

So I just implemented Responsive File Manager in a CodeIgniter application and so far it shows the dialog(modal) and it allows me to create folders and upload files, the problem comes when I select any image in the TinyMCE editor.

[image]

The same goes with any type of file not just images.

This is the actual path(admin/posts/add) in which I need to use the filemanager:

- application

  - views

    - admin

      - posts

        - add
- assets

  - Filemanager
  - Files
- system

and this is the Javascript that I have in the view file (admin/posts/add):

```
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    image_advtab: true,
    image_caption: true,
    image_title: true,
    image_prepend_url: "<?php echo base_url('assets/files/source') ?>",

        plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code",
         "print preview fullpage fullscreen template codesample toc spellchecker imagetools colorpicker textpattern help"
   ],


    toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat | responsivefilemanager',
    content_css: [
      '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
      '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
    ],

    relative_urls: false,

    formats: {
        alignleft : {selector: 'img', styles: {float: 'left', margin: '0px 10px 0px 0px'}, classes: 'img-responsive'},
        alignright : {selector: 'img', styles: {float: 'right', margin: '0px 0px 0px 10px'}, classes: 'img-responsive'},
    },

   external_filemanager_path:"<?php echo base_url('assets/filemanager/') ?>",
   filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "<?php echo base_url('assets/tinymce/plugins/responsivefilemanager/plugin.min.js') ?>"}
});
```

Thanks in advance. If you need to see my config file from the filemanager folder, then just tell me, I currently don't want to make this question longer than what it already is.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late, but maybe the problem is on your config file. I was facing the same problem and I fixed it by changing the 'upload_dir' on the config file.